# Table does not align properly after \newgeometry settings

Tags: longtable, geometry

I have a huge longtable and used \newgeometry to make it fit the page. After the table there is a short text (which I could align successfully) but another small table that comes after the text won't align properly (see picture, I made a vertical line that indicates the beginning of the small table). How can I make this table align left (like the text)? Thanks for your help!

Here is the picture: 
[image]

Here is the code: (the small table in question is at the end of it)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./eps/}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\oneS}{\ensuremath{{}^{\textstyle *}}}
\newcommand{\twoS}{\ensuremath{{}^{\textstyle **}}}
\begin{document}


\newgeometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\thispagestyle{empty}
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{l S[table-format=-1.4] S[table-format=-1.4] S[table-format=-3.2] S[table-format=-5.2] S[table-format= 7.2] S[table-format=-3.2] S[table-format=-3.2] S[table-format=-3.2] S[table-format=-3.2]  @{\hspace{0.8cm}} r r r r } 
\caption{Summary statistics}\\
\toprule
{Future e.g. underlying asset}  & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Daily returns on long-only 
positions} &  \multicolumn{4}{l}{Ljung-Box } & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Avg. vol. (\$ mil.)} 
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{Avg. open interest} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(r){7-10} \cmidrule(r){11-12} \cmidrule(r){13-14}
&  { Mean (\%) } & { Std. (\%) } & { Skew. (\%) }  & { Kurt. (\%) } & { Jarque-Bera } 
& { (5) } & { (20) } & { (60) } & { (120) } & {2000} & {2014} & {2000} & {2014} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
{Future e.g. underlying asset}  & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Daily returns on long-only 
positions} &  \multicolumn{4}{l}{Ljung-Box } & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Avg. vol. (\$ mil.)} 
&         \multicolumn{2}{l}{Avg. open interest} \\
 \cmidrule(r){2-6} \cmidrule(r){7-10} \cmidrule(r){11-12} \cmidrule(r){13-14}
&  { Mean (\%) } & { Std. (\%) } & { Skew. (\%) }  & { Kurt. (\%) } & { Jarque-Bera } &
{ (5) } & { (20) } & { (60) } & { (120) } & {2000} & {2014} & {2000} & {2014} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule \multicolumn{14}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Frozen Concentrated Orange Juice    &   -0.0184 &   1.8845  &   -8.68       &   764.51  
\twoS   &   3170.82 \twoS   &   20.61   \twoS   &   43.77   \twoS   &   98.60   \twoS   
&   150.82  \oneS   &   88  &   37  &   25727   &   16991   \\
\end{longtable}

\noindent {\emph Notes:} The Jarque-Bera statistic tests the null hypothesis that the 
daily returns are normally distributed. The Ljung-Box statistic tests the null 
hypothesis that daily return residuals exhibit no autocorrelation for a fixed number of
lags (L). The average dollar volume is the notional value of contracts for all maturity
months traded on an average day, defined as: number of contracts traded x futures price 
x multiplier x exchange rate. The reason that there is no volume and open interest data 
for the currency futures is because they were constructed as forwards from spot 
exchange rates and the country specific interest rate term structure. Also there was no
volume and open interest data available for contracts from the London Metals Exchange 
(LME) before September 2004. 

% SMALL TABLE
\begin{tabular}{ |  r @{\hspace{0.1cm}} l }
  * & Indicate statistical significance at the 5\% level. \\
  ** &  Indicate statistical significance at the 1\% level. \\
\end{tabular}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

Comment: You just need a `\noindent` before the last `tabular`.  Being created in horizontal mode, `tabular` are subject to the rules of indentation like any other text.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes an answer? :)

Comment: do you really intend to have just the "N" in "Notes" be italic?  if not, you should enter it as `\emph{Notes}` -- `\emph` takes an argument, like `\textit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate my comment as an answer, the final table is indented as a paragraph, and can be remedied by placing a `\noindent` prior to the final `tabular` block.

Excerpt:

```
% SMALL TABLE
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ |  r @{\hspace{0.1cm}} l }
  * & Indicate statistical significance at the 5\% level. \\
  ** &  Indicate statistical significance at the 1\% level. \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The `tabular` environment works in horizontal mode and thus the whole table acts, for all practical purposes, like a very large letter.  You will find if you place text immediately prior to the `tabular` block without an intervening `\par` or double-blank line (or some environment like `table`) that the `tabular` will appear on the same line as and immediately following the text.  Likewise at the end of `tabular` block:

```
% SMALL TABLE
\noindent XYZ\begin{tabular}{ |  r @{\hspace{0.1cm}} l }
  * & Indicate statistical significance at the 5\% level. \\
  ** &  Indicate statistical significance at the 1\% level. \\
\end{tabular}ZYX
```

[image]

Comment: Ah nice! Thank you Steven for your help and the thorough answer.